# Excel - 0 values do not show up after using custom formula

Tags: excel, cell, zero

I have been searching a lot but did not find answer which would solve my problem.

I have a column with numbers: http://scr.hu/0r7w/rddar

0, 1, 2, 3 and so on..

I want to convert it to Index="#" where # is the actual cell value.

I selected entire column -> right click -> format cells -> Custom -> in Type field entered: "Index="''#''

The result of this operation is as follows: http://scr.hu/0r7w/3341s

As you can see the cells which contained 0 value are displaying now as Index='''', I need the 0 to display after I used the formula, Index=''0'', how can I gain it?

NOTE: When I double click the cell I can see the 0 there but upon saving the document it is still not there, any advises? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: "Index="''#0''

The 0 indicates how many numeric characters you want to display where the value is not blank or null. Eg "Index="''#000'' would return Index=000, Index=001 etc.